# How to do between-group three-way anova (type 3 sums of square)

Tags: r, anova

I want to compare two unbalanced groups of subjects (G): independent variables are factor A and B, dependent variable is C.

My professor told me to use type 3 SS ANOVA, but I am not sure whether the following is correct.

```
Anova(lm(C ~ G * A * B + Error(Subject/(A*B)) + G, mydata, 
          contrasts=list(A=contr.sum, B=contr.sum)), type=3))
```

Note: `A` and `B` are within subject as well because all subjects did all levels of A and B. `G` (group) is between subject. `Subject` is subject id. Data set is `mydata`.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23197) question?

Comment: My concern is A and B are within-subject factors. How should I handle that in lm method? Thanks.